# What hostname did the client use to connect to my TCP server?

Tags: tcp, server, port

In http the client supplies the hostname it used to connect to the service with. Now, for bare TCP connections, is there something similar one can do? My scenario is I have a service that has multiple open TCP ports and that works fine, but for convenience I would like to use the same port and subdomains. Is there any layer I can add on top (like a load balancer), or change the service? I have control over most things, basically anything goes.

Example:
Today I can connect to two TCP services like so: `foobar.com:1001` and `foobar.com:1002`. Is it possible to have e.g. `service-1.foobar.com:1000` go to `foobar.com:1001` and `service-2.foobar.com:1000` go to `foobar.com:1002`.

Answer (score 1):

Different services can bind to same port but on different IP. Hence different domains shall resolve to different IPs : Port combination [where Port is same for all services]. And you can use Proxy service as from HA Proxy to route connections to final destination.

Comment: So there is no way to do this without having different IP numbers. As I suspected. Do you have some sources on this?

Comment: Not sure, I got your question. You wanted to hide `foo..:1001` & `foo...:1002` behind a `Proxy1:1000` and `Proxy2:1000` isn't?

Comment: yeah, that's correct. Or not ncecessary hide, it's fine if foo..:1001 etc is still available, it's more of a shorthand of sorts.

Comment: So Proxy services,like HA Proxy shall bind on Proxy1:1000 and Proxy2:1000. Each having their own destination.

Comment: What is "HA Proxy"? I understand this is very easy to set up if you have different IPs for all the hosts. So to clarify, it is impossible to do without using different IP numbers. Do you have any sources?

Comment: Yes. Same IP:Port means one single entity. One single process bound to that IP:Port and providing the service

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136531/discussion-between-vidstige-and-prabhu).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly based on your example then no it is not possible. In this case, there is no difference between an HTTP and TCP connection.

In both cases, the hostname is simply resolved to an ip address. If you setup DNS resolution for foobar.com, service-1.foobar.com, service-2.foobar.com to point to the same ip address then they will all go to the same machine.

I have at times needed to have a service running on a different port internally than it is accessible externally. For that, if you are running on Linux, you can simply use iptables to do the port forwarding.

You can find other stack overflow questions/answers for setting up the port forwarding.

https://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables